# Return the two largest integers in an array of values

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to return the two largest integers from my int array.
I am able to return the largest and the smallest fine, but I cannot get my algorithm to return the two largest. 
Any help is greatly appreciated here.

Please forgive any errors in my code. This is a practice session and the question has been taken from last years exam material at university.

Here is my code:

```
public class TwoLargestIntsArray {

public static void main(String [] args){

    int [] values = new int[5];

    values[0] = 5;
    values[1] = 10;
    values[2] = 15;
    values[3] = 20;
    values[4] = 25;

    System.out.println(twoLargest(values));
    System.out.println();

}

public static int twoLargest(int values[]){

    int largestA = values[0];
    int largestB = values[0];

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            if(values[i] > largestA){
                largestA = values[i];
            }
            if(values[i] < largestA){
                largestB = values[i];   
            }

    }
    return largestA + largestB; 
}

}
```

Comment: the array is one dimensional array or n dimensional array?

Comment: I already give an answer :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write

```
public static int[] twoLargest(int values[]){
    int largestA = Integer.MIN_VALUE, largestB = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for(int value : values) {
        if(value > largestA) {
            largestB = largestA;
            largestA = value;
        } else if (value > largestB) {
            largestB = value;
        }
    }
    return new int[] { largestA, largestB }; 
}
```

Comment: Hey Peter, it has thrown an exception:
    Exception in thread "main"      java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
 at TwoLargestIntsArray.twoLargest(TwoLargestIntsArray.java:22)
 at TwoLargestIntsArray.main(TwoLargestIntsArray.java:13)

Comment: I amended the for loop as I figured it was that. However the output is this - [I@56e5b723
Any thoughts?

Comment: I fixed the loop too.  You need `Arrays.toString(array)` to get a sensible output for an array.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Where does Arrays.toString(array) go in the code?

Comment: What result will this code produce when the input array is: [1, 2]?

Comment: @stanislaw.osinski it should produce `[ 2, 1 ]`

Comment: Well, on my machine it produces: [2, -2147483648]

Comment: @stanislaw.osinski You are right. The answer should be fixed now.

Answer (score 9):

```
public static void twoLargest(int values[]){

    int largestA = values[0];
    int largestB = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            if(values[i] > largestA){
                largestB = largestA;
                largestA = values[i];
            }
            else if (values[i] > largestB && values[i] != largestA) {
                largestB = values[i];
            }
    }
    System.out.println("Largest - " + largestA);
    System.out.println("2nd largest Largest - " + largestB);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I changed my array and values[0] = 30. This makes largestB = 0.

Comment: Why did you make largestB = -1 just out of interest?

Comment: [Introduction To Algorithms](http://books.google.com.tw/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA185&dq=second+smallest+element&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=6lOGUd-_BsPYigePkIHwCQ&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=second%20smallest%20element&f=false) said that the second smallest (of course the second largest) of n elements can be found with `n + ceil(lg n) - 2` comparisons in the worst case. How to approach that?

Comment: Really? Ok I will look at that. Thanks for your help. Although it seems a small question, the responses have been varied. Interesting.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson How would you tackle this?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is there a way to do it do you know?

Answer (score 2):

```
   //Java8&9 makes this easier with a cleaner code
   int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 4, 57, 54, 656, 4};       
    int maxSize = 2;
    Arrays.stream(numbers) //stream
    .boxed()  //to Integer Object
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()) //sorted
    .limit(maxSize )  //keep N values
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

NB.  We could use this astuce with any bean Object implementing comparable or by using a related custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test
{

public static int[] findTwoHighestDistinctValues(int[] array)
{
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int secondMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int value:array)
    {
        if (value > max)
        {
            secondMax = max;
            max = value;
        }
        else if (value > secondMax && value < max)
        {
            secondMax = value;
        }
    }
    return new int[] { max, secondMax };
}

public static void main(String []args)
{
    int [] values = new int[5];
        values[0] = 5;
        values[1] = 10;
        values[2] = 15;
        values[3] = 20;
        values[4] = 25;
    int []ar = findTwoHighestDistinctValues(values);
    System.out.println("1 = "+ar[0]);
    System.out.println("2 = "+ar[1]);
}  
}
```

OUTPUT:

1 = 25

2 = 20

Comment: I'd compare like (value >= max) if there are any duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a single function return 2 values. You either have to wrap them in an array, or use reference parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Pass array to be filled with values:

```
public static void twoLargest(int [] values, int [] ret){
    //...
    ret[0] = largestA;
    ret[1] = largestB;
}


int [] ret = new int [2];
twoLargest(values, ret);
// now ret[0] is largestA
// and ret[1] is largestB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public static int[] twoLargest(int values[]){

    int[] result = new int[2];
    int largestA = 0;
    int largestB = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

            if(values[i] > largestA){
            largestB = largestA;
            largestA = values[i];
        }
    }
     result[0] = largestA;
     result[1] = largestB;

    return result; 
}
```

Comment: The largest values could be negative.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming it will help you in case you are able to get the largest, secondlargest, thirdlargest and so on from a function. I have created such a one :

```
public static int xLargest(int values[], int largeIndex)
```

Just pass the array and the largeIndex, for largest send 1 , for second largest send 2 and so on.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class XLargestIntArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = new int[5];

        values[0] = 5;
        values[1] = 10;
        values[2] = 15;
        values[3] = 20;
        values[4] = 25;

        System.out.println(xLargest(values,2));
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static int xLargest(int values[], int largeIndex) {

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
            intList.add(values[index]);
        }
        Collections.sort(intList);
        return intList.get(intList.size() - largeIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can sort an Array. You don't have to create a List of Integer, just to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use nested class to store results of your computing. For example:

```
  private static class Result {

    int largestA;
    int largestB;

    Result(int largestA, int largestB) {
        this.largestA = largestA;
        this.largestB = largestB;
    }
}
```

And then receive data something like:

```
Result result = twoLargest(values);
System.out.println(result.largestA);
System.out.println(result.largestB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Nilesh Jadav covers all cases. Answer by @Peter Lawrey fails in cases where the array has largest value is the last element. for example [10,2,5,1,8,20] returns 20 and 8 with the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] numbers = new int[]{1, 2, 5, 4, 57, 54, 656, 4};
    int temp = numbers[0];
    int max = temp;
    int lastMax = temp;

    for (int index = 1; index < numbers.length; index++){
        int currentIndex = numbers[index];

        // check any time is it bigger than current maximum value
        max = Math.max(max, currentIndex);

        // if is grow up then should be max != temp; set old Max in last or 
        // is not group up but current index is bigger then last index update last max value
        lastMax = max != temp ? temp : Math.max(currentIndex, lastMax);

        temp = max;
    }

    System.out.println("Last max: " + lastMax);
    System.out.println("Max:" + max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void printTwoMaxNumberWithoutSortMethod(int[] input) {
    int max=0,lastMax=0;
    lastMax=input[0];
    max=input[0];
    for(int i=1;i<input.length;i++)
    {
        if(lastMax<input[i] & max<input[i])
        {
            lastMax=max;
            max=input[i];

        }
    }
    System.out.println("lastMax="+lastMax+" : max="+max);

}
```

Comment: can you document your code plz?, either in the code or with words

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TwoLargestIntArray {


    public static void main(String [] args){

        int a[]  = new int[5];

        a[0] = 110;
        a[1] = 50;
        a[2] = 15;
        a[3] = 30;
        a[4] = 60;

        System.out.println(twoLargest(a));
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static int twoLargest(int a[]){

        int firstMax = 0;
        int secondMax = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){

                if(a[i]>firstMax) {
                    secondMax=firstMax;
                    firstMax = a[i];}
                    else if (a[i]>secondMax) {
                        secondMax= a[i];
                    }

                    }




        return  firstMax + secondMax; 
    }}
```

Comment: That *preview* window exists for a reason: so you can check your input before submitting it. Please take some time and properly indent/format all of your code. There is no point in dumping code that is super hard to read, just because you didn't spend the 10 seconds to remove empty lines or indent in a reasonable way!

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not an issue here, which it shouldn't be on small arrays, this could be done with less code.

The most straightforward solution is to simply sort the array and return its last, and next to last value:

```
public static int[] twoLargest(int[] values) {
    Arrays.sort(values);
    return new int[]{values[values.length - 1], values[values.length - 2]};
}
```

The time complexity of the above code is *O(n log (n))*, as stated in the Javadoc for [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)):

> Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

If expected input is an array with less than two elements, some error handling would need to be added, such as throwing an exception.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int Compute(int _arrValues[]){

        int _intX = _arrValues[0];
        int _intY = _arrValues[1];

        for(int i = 2; i < _arrValues.length; i++){

                if(_arrValues[i] > _intX){
                    _intX= values[i];
                }
                else if(_arrValues[i] > _intY){
                    _intY = values[i];   
                }
        }
        return _intX + _intY; 
    }
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers. See also [answer]. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5244995)

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
int [] array1={10,2,5,1,8,20};

int largest= array1[0];

int seclargest=array1[0];

for (int i=1;i<array1.length;i++)
{
    if(largest <= array1[i])
    {
        seclargest=largest;
        largest=array1[i];  
    }   

}

System.out.println("largest and second largest are:" +largest + " " +seclargest);
```

Comment: this fails for following input: array1 = {6, 9, 3, 1, 7}