# Return the two largest integers of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have figured out how to return the largest integer of my array.

```
int[] a = new int[] { 2, 22, 4, 6745, 45, 999, 1000, 1, 5747, 454 };

public int method(int[] a) { 
  int max = Arrays.stream(a).max().getAsInt();
  return max;
}
```

However, I still did not find a way to reutnr the largest TWO integers.
Could you help my out? I am still a beginner, so make it simple pls :)

Comment: I tried them all before, unfortunately, neither of those answers worked properly :l

Comment: I can assure you that [Peter Lawrey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16385929/3788176) works.

Comment: For some reason, it only returns "[I@2a139a55" though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have a wonderful day :)