# finding two max values in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me please?  I want to find the maximum and the 2nd maximum value of an Array using a method. I already know how I can get the Minimum and the 2nd minimum value, it's basically almost the same, but the output is still wrong ? 
This is the method how I find the two minimum values.

```
public static void minimum( int [] a ) {
int min;
for (int i = 0; i< a.length; i++)  {
    for (int j = min = i; j< a.length; j++) {
        if (a[j] < a[min]) min = j;
        if(min>i) {
            int temp = a [i];
            a [i] = a [min];
            a [min] = temp;

        } 
}
```

so , to find the maximum I thought it's just to change **<**  to **>** from this line : 
if (a[j] **<** a[min]) min = j;`
so, instead of swapping smaller values, bigger values will be swapped. But it's wrong and I don't get it.

Thank you !

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if(min>i)`?

Comment: if there is a smaller value , the smaller value from an Array should be the Minimum ( min = j) ; , so if  i is smaller than min, the values should swap

Comment: Your code is really confusing. Why are you doing any swaps at all? Why are you not returning anything from your method (I think you have to return an array, for example, with 2 values - max and next max), or at least print these 2 values?

Comment: That is a sorting algorithm, to **sort the entire array**. Seems to be an inefficient [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). Which means that the 2 smallest values are the first 2 values, and the 2 largest values are the last 2 values. Rename the method to `sort` and you're done. --- But be aware that sorting the entire list is the least effective way to find the 2 smallest/largest values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return the two largest integers in an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384472/return-the-two-largest-integers-in-an-array-of-values) Take a look at this - there you can find effective way of doing it without sorting the entire array.

Comment: @GBlodgett Code doesn't do `j = min`. Code does `j = min = i`, i.e. assigning value of `i` to both `j` and `min` at the same time. No compilation error. Code works fine, see [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245833/finding-two-max-values-in-java#comment95316278_54245833).

Comment: @Andreas , yes I sort the entire array to find the max/min values :-) I thought, if i can sort the array from the smallest to the biggest values , then I can sort it the other way too ( to practice) , so that the max values are the first 2 values of the array, but I failed.

Comment: @user10917325 Probably because the method is a **flawed** implementation of the [selection sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). The `if(min>i)` block with the swap code needs to be *outside* the `j` loop. --- Once you do that, simply change `(a[j] < a[min])` to `(a[j] > a[min])` to sort descending.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code by yourself,the code may help you:

```
public static void maxNum(int[] a) {
    int length = a.length;
    if (length == 0) {
        System.out.println("the length of input array 0");
        return;
    }
    if (length == 1) {
        System.out.println("the max is " + a[0]);
        return;
    }
    int max = a[0] > a[1] ? a[0] : a[1];
    int secondMax = a[0] > a[1] ? a[1] : a[0];
    for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
        int value = a[i];
        if (value > max) {
            int tmp = max;
            max = value;
            secondMax = tmp;
        } else if (value > secondMax) {
            secondMax = value;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the max is " + max);
    System.out.println("the second max is " + secondMax);
}
```

If you don't want to code yourself,you can use tools in java like `Arrays.sort()` to sort the array first and get what you want.