# Is there a faster way to find the highest pair-sum of an int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sum

Is there a different way using the java Collection that makes this code faster ? Is there any another way to make this code faster?
Is ArrayList the right choice for this kind of problem?

```
import java.util.*;

class Main{

public static int GetHighestPairSum(int[] L)
{
    int largest = L[0];
    int index = 0;
    int secondlargest = L[0];

    ArrayList<Integer> I = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i<L.length; i++)
    {
        I.add(L[i]);

        if (i == 0)
        {
            largest = L[i];
        }
        else 
        {   
            if (largest < L[i])
            {
                largest = L[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

    I.remove(index);
    secondlargest = Collections.max(I);

    return largest + secondlargest;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

     int[] testarr = new int[] {1,2,3,23,67,100,2,11,3,2,6,7,1,13,4,7,9,34,7,3,2,1,100}; 
     System.out.println(GetHighestPairSum(testarr));
}
```

}

Comment: Why not just loop through the `Array` and have a variable for the largest and second largest instead of copying it to a `List`, looping once to find the largest, removing it, and then calling `Collections.max`?

Comment: @GBlodgett Can you post some code?

Comment: A `Stream` solution might be more readable: `Arrays.stream(L).sorted().skip(L.length - 2).sum();`. However, the time complexity of this is `O(n log n)` whereas an `O(n)` solution is trivial with a single for-loop and two pointers.

Comment: Already answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384472/return-the-two-largest-integers-in-an-array-of-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return the two largest integers in an array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384472/return-the-two-largest-integers-in-an-array-of-values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this implementation, you'll have to go over the list twice.
A more performant approach would be to hold two variables for the largest and second largest elements, and update them both as you go. Note that this can be done by iterating the array directly, and there's no need to copy it to an `ArrayList`, as @GBlodgett's answer suggests.

A similar solution which could support any number of elements could use a [`PriorityQueue`]:

```
public static int getHighestTuppleSum(int[] arr, int n) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue(arr.length);
    for (int i : arr) {
        if (pq.size() < n) {
            pq.add(i);
        }
        if (pq.peek() < i) {
            pq.poll();
            pq.add(i);
        }
    }
    return pq.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum(); 
}
```